# ZF2 site on IIS 7 subdomain routing not working

Tags: iis, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a shared Windows hosting account on Ez-DomainNameRegistration. I have setup a subdomain that routes to a subfolder and uploaded my Zend framework website to the folder. FYI: the website works on my local pc on IIS 7. The problem I have is that the layout of the site is correctly loaded, but the controller-action routing does not work. Instead of the view of the action I get the 404 error view. My guess is that it has something to do with the url routing.

In the route folder (the subfolder pointed to by the subdomain) I have the following web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
<rule name="Imported Rule 14" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|txt|svg)$" negate="true" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="public/index.php{R:1}" />
</rule>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 15" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

And in the public folder I have the following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^.*$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern=""   ignoreCase="false" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
</conditions>
<action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^.*$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Is there something I can change to make the routing work in side a subdomain/subfolder on iis 7?